# Where to look for good material regarding real-life applications of vectors?

Tags: vectors

I've been given this task in an assignment:

"Research an example of the use of vectors, and explain how the mathematics is used, for example in engineering, computer animation, gaming, 3-D printing or GPS technology."

However, from searching the internet I just find a lot of forum discussions and wiki answer pages. Wikipedia is also more about explaining the concept of the vectors rather than how they're applied in real life. So I was wondering if anyone know where I could look. I need some source that I can actually cite, a credible source with actual details. Otherwise I'll only end up with a scant answer I found through a random claim on the internet, which is hardly a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally anytime you care about more than one number at a time, vectors are important.  The question is so broad as to be almost meaningless, it is like asking "what are some real life uses of fractions"?

For instance, in 3d animation you need to store millions of vectors describing the vertices of polygons.  You need to compute normal vector to these surfaces to deal with lighting correctly, for instance.  You need rotation and projection matrices to deal with projecting objects onto the screen, or moving a camera around the object.  You need to solve vector valued differential equations to smoothly and realistically model just about any physical phenomena in the animation such as water flowing, hair blowing, or rocks exploding!

Comment: For an actual source, you might be interested in looking through udacities 3d graphics mooc.

Comment: Thank you, that udacity site works fine!

Comment: Actually, going through it, there's not much to cite here. I personally realize the importance of vectors, and I can think of tons of examples how they are used. It's just that I need a source, because I'm supposed to do research.